# reCaptcha v3 worker-src none

Tags: javascript

I keep getting this error in my Console when I run reCaptcha V3:

```
recaptcha__en.js:310 [Report Only] Refused to create a worker from 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/webworker.js?hl=en&v=v1548052318968' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "worker-src 'none'".
```

The script runs ok, but it keeps looking for the worker and I have no clue where to fix this. Is this a common issue or is it something I missed in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a property in your HTTP header that modify Content-Security-Policy.

Can you inspect your HTTP header on the page and see if you have : 'worker-src 'none'' somewhere ?

This property disallow all the web workers in your page, you can modify it to allow sources, see more in the MDN documentation :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/worker-src